# How do I check if an NSTimer is running?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nstimer

I have an IBAction where upon the button being pressed, it creates an unscheduled timer. Then, if that same timer has already started, //do something, else start the timer which was created.
Here is what I have so far:

```
- (IBAction)button1Press {



 NSMethodSignature *sgn = [self methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(onTick:)];
 NSInvocation *inv = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature: sgn];
 [inv setTarget: self];
 [inv setSelector:@selector(onTick:)];

 NSTimer *tapTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval: 1.0
           invocation:inv 
              repeats:NO];



 if (/*tapTimer is running*/) {//do something
  }else{



  NSRunLoop *runner = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    [runner addTimer: tapTimer forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
  }

 }
```

My problem is what to put as the condition. If I put tapTimer isValid or != nil then it always returns true, because tapTimer is already declared. I do not want to invalidate or nil out the timer because the main purpose of the button is to *only* do the action if the button is pressed twice in a time interval of 1 second.

If there is a completely different approach to do what I want then please do tell!

Thanks loads!

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand so far, I see that you are attempting to check whether tapTimer is running or not. I have one suggestion. Use a variable for indicating whether you are having tapTimer running or not. When you run the timer, you change this variable to true, and when the timer's time hits 0 and invoke the method you have selected, you change this variable to false in this method.

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a nil check to determine if your timer is running or not.

```
...
//Define _tapTimer in .h

if (_tapTimer) {//do something
}
else{
   _tapTimer = [[NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval: 1.0
           invocation:inv 
              repeats:NO] retain];
   NSRunLoop *runner = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
   [runner addTimer: _tapTimer forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}

...

-(void)timerFired:(NSTimer*)timer
{
   if(timer == _tapTimer)
   {
      //Handle timerfired
      [_tapTimer release], _tapTimer = nil;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This worked, but only when I removed the if(timer == _tapTimer). I don't see what this was supposed to do?

Comment: Thats only if you have multiple timers calling the same fired event. Its not really necessary. The timers also have userinfo dictionaries if you wanted to use multiple.

Answer (score -1):

You can query the RunLoop to know if there is such a timer inside the loop

```
CFRunLoopRef loopRef = [[runner currentRunLoop] getCFRunLoop];
Boolean timerAdded = CFRunLoopContainsTimer(loopRef, (CFRunLoopTimerRef)timer ,kCFRunLoopDefaultMode)

if (timerAdded)
{
    ...
}
```

but, I haven't tested that code yet